# How to run the code only through visible tabs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather trivial problem. I have this code [which is worksheet-specific as you can see, what I need is that it goes through all visible [non-hidden] worksheets, can you please advise?]:

```
Sub TRANS_to_EDD()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim LTD As Worksheet
Dim INF As Long, RSP As Long

Set WB = Workbooks("XX.xlsm")
Set LTD = WB.Sheets("LimitedCo")
Set EDD = WB.Sheets("EDD")

INF = LTD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To INF
If LTD.Range("I" & i).Value = "Reject" Then
    LTD.Range("I" & i).Offset(0, -6).Copy
    EDD.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next i

For i = 2 To INF
If LTD.Range("I" & i).Value = "Reject" Then
    LTD.Range("I" & i).Offset(0, -5).Copy
    EDD.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thanks

PS. EDD always stays as it is the end destination.

Comment: `If WB.Visible = true then` ...

Comment: `.visible` does this help?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that's the workbook.   It's the worksheets, not sure what is actually required the loop or that bit :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - You're right, for some reason I read `WB`, `LTD` and `EDD` as 3 worksheets... got to get my eyes checked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just loop through worksheets, checking if they're visible:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Workbooks("XX.xlsm").Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ' Do things
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work. Nothing happens when I'm triggering it from EDD sheet. If I select one of the visible sheets and then trigger it, it will do the operation, then I have to go to another sheet (activate it manually) and then trigger the code.

Comment: @WestRay  Did you change "xx.xlsm" to your workbook name?

Comment: @WestRay to be fair, this is the way to loop through worksheets. (Downvoter care to mention why the vote?)  Where is this sub stored and being called from? It's unclear how you'd incorporate this into your OP code, but with some quick research you should be able to get it.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - I think that goes without saying. brucewayne I will work on it tonight and tomorrow and let you know - but at the moment it doesn't work (am surprised as well).

Comment: @WestRay - However you implement this, are you making sure to link your new ranges to each `ws`? How isn't this working, can you please clarify *where* this code runs from (worksheet module or workbook module?), and make sure you don't have any `.Select` or `.Activate` in the final code.  Again, this is *the way* to loop through worksheets (alternative is to use an `i` counter I suppose), so any issues are further in the code I think.

Comment: @WestRay  :)  You'd be surprised, I've written an answer using B1:B10 and had comment back saying, thanks, but my range is A1:A10.  What is the issue with this code?  What are you running in the "do things" section?

Comment: It runs from the workbook module, in the dothings I call my code which has no 'select' or 'activate' in it, it's basically this: Sub test_visibleonly()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim INF As Long, RSP As Long

Set WB = Workbooks("xx.xlsm")
Set EDD = WB.Sheets("EDD")

INF = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To INF
If Range("I" & i).Value = "Further Information Needed" Then
    Range("I" & i).Offset(0, -6).Copy
    EDD.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Comment: I think I have found the issue, the tab that is visible needs to be activated so the code [I have] can execute on it specifically (we are assuming we don't know tab names).